# How to create an executable for a python file using Pyinstaller that uses files locally

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pyinstaller, file-conversion

I have this code(file named scrape.py):

```
from fredapi import Fred
import pandas as pd
import os

fred= Fred(api_key= 'API_KEY')
data = fred.get_series('LMUNRRTTDEM156S', frequency = 'm', observation_start="2010-01-01")
data.to_csv('germanyUnemployment.csv', header=['Germany Unemployment'], index_label='date')

data1 = fred.get_series('DEUCPIALLMINMEI', frequency = 'm', observation_start="2010-01-01")
data1.to_csv('germanyInflation.csv', header=['Germany Inflation'], index_label='date')

data2 = fred.get_series('EXUSEU', frequency = 'm', observation_start="2010-01-01")
data2.to_csv('germanyConversion.csv', header=['Germany(Euro)/ dollar'], index_label='date')

df1 = pd.read_csv('germanyUnemployment.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('germanyInflation.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('germanyConversion.csv')
df4 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'date')
dfMerge= pd.merge(df4, df3, on = 'date')
dfMerge.set_index('date', inplace = True)
dfMerge.to_csv('Germany.csv')
os.remove("germanyUnemployment.csv")
os.remove("germanyInflation.csv")
os.remove("germanyConversion.csv")
```

I am trying to create an executable file using PyInstaller, i use the command: pyinstaller --onefile scrape.py. This creates all the folders and files as expected by the actual executable file doesn't give the correct output. I suspect this has something to do with the creation then reading and finally the removal of 3 csv files. I tried adding the files but no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem. If there’s an error message please edit the __full__ error message into your question. If you’re going to bundle the three csv files into the onefile executable, then these are going to be present every time you run the executable, so what’s the purpose in deleting these files?

Comment: @barny There is no error message, it just doesn't output anything or create the single file Germany.csv as it should, i have testing this output in terminal and it does work so i think maybe another command for pyinstaller is needed. The reason i delete the 3 files at the end is that they have been merged into 1 file namely Germany.csv. Thanks

Comment: a) don’t create the exe with noconsole, and b) run from commandline and add some simple print statements at each step until you find out where it’s dying.

Comment: Add details of how you’re building the exe and also provide enough code and data that this is runnable here. _minimal_ code and data.

Comment: I didn't create the exe with noconsole, I just used the console to check the python code was correct ie just python3 scrape.py. When it comes to building the exe i used the command "pyinstaller --onefile scrape.py". This command led to folders and the executable file itself being created but the executable file does not output the same things as the python file (ie when running python3 scrape.py). So, i believe there is an additional commands to pyinstaller in order to use these csv files in the code

Comment: did you try adding some print statements before and between the points where the csv files are read - get anything? If it's not producing germany.csv then it must be failing somewhere before that. Check the code before that by some debugging process; adding print statements is a primitive but effective way of doing this.

Comment: @barny I did do multiple print statements as you suggested.  The error occurs here: read_file = pd.read_csv(‘PathTo/Germany.csv')
print("GOT POINT 9")
read_file.to_excel (‘PathTo/Germany.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
print("GOT POINT 10"). This returns this error when using pyinstaller: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PathTo/Germany.csv'. This seems weird to me since the file is created in this path when executing this line of code which was executed successfully: dfMerge.to_csv('Germany.csv'). So i don't understand how im getting a FileNotFoundError. Thanks

Comment: try printing the `io.path.abspath()` of each of the actual filenames you're trying to read or write

Comment: @barny i tried as you suggested and the path is correct, what this os.path.abspath('Germany.csv') returned is exactly what i have in the the: read_file = pd.read_csv(‘PathTo/Germany.csv'). Is this an fundamental issue with pyinstaller ie it cannot create files? Not to sure what else to do, i have tried the print statements and the path checking. Thanks

Comment: Of course it's not a fundamental issue with PyInstaller; it's your code/environment/assumptions. Sorry I meant `os.path.abspath`. So you can see the file yourself at the os.path.abspath('Germany.csv') location, but your code can't read the file there? Mysterious. Unlikely to be fixable from anywhere but your seat.

Comment: Break it down into smaller parts, e.g. write some simpler code that only reads a file; when that works from PyInstaller exe, write some code that writes a file then reads it, etc.